# Direct Messaging custom slack bot built on node.js

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I have built a slack bot using the slack/bots apis in node.js: https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started

Currently, it is working fine when I type `<bot> help` in a channel I have set up for using webhooks. I am trying to run those same commands in a DM with the bot using the app.event('app_mention',...) method but it is not working. its like the message doesn't register in a DM with the bot for some reason but it works in a public channel. code snippet below:

```
app.event('app_mention', async ({ event, client}) => {
    console.log(event);
    const text = event.text;
    const parentMessageId = event.ts;
    const eventChannel = event.channel;
    if (text.includes("help")) {
        console.log(event);
        try {
            await client.chat.postMessage({
                channel: eventChannel,
                text: helpMessage,
                thread_ts: parentMessageId
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
```

I should have permissions set up correctly as well. I basically have all the permissions that I can add for the bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the `app_mention` api specifically mentions that this event does not work with DMs.

> Messages sent to your app in **direct message** conversations are **not
> dispatched via app_mention**, whether the app is explicitly mentioned or
> otherwise. Subscribe to **message.im** events to receive messages directed
> to your bot user in direct message conversations.

Check here : https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention

Comment: Thanks. Thats good to know. I tried the message.im option but that gives me an error: AppInitializationError: Although the document mentions "message.im",it is not a valid event type. Use "message" instead. If you want to filter message events, you can use event.channel_type for it.

Any idea  what I could do there?

Comment: The issue is not clear from your comment, but you should use 'message' event like : app.event('message',callbackFn), required scope will be 'im.history' for dms. Details : https://api.slack.com/events/message

Comment: I have app.event('message',...) as well but that doesn't register with bot. I have the permission too.

Comment: Have you subscribed to relevant events? Any screenshots of the errors and configurations?

Comment: ohh that was the problem. I hadn't subscribed to the message.im events! dang it. thanks for the help

Comment: Can you mark the answer as 'Accepted', if this resolves your issue?